# How do I figure out what to import or require for a module?

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules, laravel-mix

I have imported some modules from npm to use with Laravel Mix. Usually, I can put a require or import statement at the top of the file using the same module name as I used when I typed "npm install." But sometimes this doesn't work at it can't resolve the module.

I checked that the module is listed in package.json and that the folder exists in the /node_modules directory.

When I look inside the node_modules folder, I can find the module folder which has src/ and a dist/ folders with JS files inside them; there is also a package.json inside the module folder. However, it still won't import. How can I figure out what path and files the require or import statements are trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

Could use static analysis tool, like sonarlint to inspect your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide more info or code snippet i could help more but generally if the package was properly configured just a `import` is enough but if it does not import you can simply use for example `require('package-name/dist/main.js');`.